# laravel vue pagination return invalid prop type check failed for prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I started working with nuxt js and i have installed **laravel-vue-pagination** plugin and i don't know why i get this error message on my console system :

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "data". Expected Object, got Array
```

this is my code :

```
getResults (page = 0) {
  this.$axios.$get('mydomain.com/api/Customer/loadCustomers/' + page).then((response) => {
    this.laravelData = response.data
  })
},
```

This is my data :

```
data () {
return {
  laravelData: {},
  formFields: {},
  search: null,
  editMode: true,
  customerId: null,
  refresh: false
}
}
```

Html page code :

```
<pagination :data="laravelData" @pagination-change-page="getResults" />
```

also i have already registred the components using :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.component('pagination', require('laravel-vue-pagination'))
```

my json feedback :

```
{
"success": false,
"total": 6,
"per_page": 10,
"current_page": 0,
"last_page": 1,
"data": [
    {
        "id": "34",
        "customer_name": "Philippe Lesen",
        "customer_company_name": "doxydiwapo@mailinator.com",
        "customer_email": "musybecapa@mailinator.net",
        "customer_phone": "+4382251059",
        "customer_fax": "+1 (223) 134-7141",
        "customer_mobile": "+4382251059",
        "customer_website": "https://www.qusopywode.org.au",
        "customer_type": "2",
        "billing_address": "Cupiditate alias asp",
        "billing_city": "Delectus reprehende",
        "billing_state": "In velit illo ut vol",
        "billing_zip": "73660",
        "billing_country": "TH",
        "shippingaddr_id": null,
        "currency": "EUR",
        "sales_representative": null,
        "payment_condition": null,
        "payment_method": null,
        "tax_preference": "1",
        "invoice_notification": "1",
        "note": null,
        "status": null
     }
]
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed the issue using `this.laravelData = response`

Answer (score 0):

You fixed the issue.  This is why...

You declare the laravelData as an object

```
 laravelData: {},
```

but you assign it

```
this.laravelData = response.data
```

to an array

```
"data": [
```

Another fix for you might be to declare your laravalData as an array, and maybe you will see just the data, which looks like what you intended.

```
 laravelData: [],
```